# Facebook javascript connect with localhost domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create facebook connect using javascript which gives follwing error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Does is due to I am using Localhost server for testing? Do I need to purchase domain to test this or what?
Or do I need to make changes in following code:

my code:

```php
<?php
//
// uses the PHP SDK. Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
include("facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

//
// from the facebook app page
define('YOUR_APP_ID', '321849981247524');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '49fd00ce6237aff0af08fd8ca25dbc92');

//
// new facebook object to interact with facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => YOUR_APP_ID,
 'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));
//
// if user is logged in on facebook and already gave permissions
// to your app, get his data:
$userId = $facebook->getUser();

?>
<html>
<head>
 <style>body { text-align:center; font-size: 40px }</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($userId) {
 //
 // already logged? show some data
 $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);

echo "<p>YOU ARE: <strong>". $userInfo['name'] ."</strong><br/>";
echo "Your birth date is: ".$userInfo['birthday']."</p>";



} else {
 //
 // use javaascript api to open dialogue and perform
 // the facebook connect process by inserting the fb:login-button
 ?>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <fb:login-button scope='email,user_birthday'></fb:login-button>
 <?php
}
?>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId : <?=YOUR_APP_ID?>, //When I gives app ID "321849981247524" or my own created it gives error that it's not valid
 status : true,
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true,
 });

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // This is the callback if everything is ok
 window.location.reload();
 });
 };

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run in browser it shows facebook button and on click redirect to new windows to do FB loging but then shows above mentioned error!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474122/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-application-configuration)

Comment: @AnveshSaxena: Can you please just tell me what should I keep as 'App Domains' when I am using localhost server, I try to tun `http://localhost/FB/login.php`

Comment: You can leave that blank, it is optional.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know that this is an old question but here is a tested and working solution for anyone who ends up here looking for an answer:

At start `App Domains` field should be left blank.

Click 'Add Platform' button below and choose 'Website'.

In the new Website form you can add localhost in the `Site URL` field:

eg. `http://localhost:3000/`

For a visual guide with images you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493806/3009639).

Apart from this, you can actually use user123's answer, and map localhost to a local domain (eg. 'myproject.dev') and the local dev domain must be entered in the same `Site URL` field: 
eg. `http://myproject.dev/`

Answer (score 2):

You should use some alias domain when you want to connect your Facebook application with your local environment.

Try the following:

```
       Go to your etc/hosts file and add the following line:

       127.0.0.1 dev01.dev # you can change domain to whatever you want

       Go to Facebook App Dashboard and register your application using dev01.dev as domain!

       Add your Site URL (eg. http://dev01.dev/project/ )

It should works.
```

Edit: You can also check this question: Facebook development in localhost

Source: [facebook localhost developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294630/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-localhost-facebook-app-development)

Answer (score 1):

In facebook, please refer following steps if facebook javascript SDK doesn't work in chrome.

1. Keep App Domain blank
2. Site URL : localhost/App_Name

Disable all plugins from chrome. Especially Ad blocker which will give you a :

> 307 Internal Status Code

It should work.

Comment: problem is with url protocol just remove `http://` and it work fine with localhsot