# Is there a way to use Facebook API on an internal website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

For testing and educational purposes, I use an internal server which I did not set up and do not have the access to make changes outside of some write access to website folders.  While trying to setup a test page so I can learn the Facebook API, I run into the problem of:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Trying to add the URL of my test page (an internal IP address) gives an error saying:

> is invalid because it is a Facebook url

Search around, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621602/1618257) suggest using `localhost`.  Sounds like a good idea, try that.  Same error, guess the servers are not set up like that? (I'm not well versed in servers)

Is there any way I can use the Facebook API internally or will I need to learn the API and test anything on a server with an external domain?