# I can't run facebook js api from local file?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've created a HTML5 app that is not running on any webserver. It's just html and javascript, and I want to make my users login so they could save their score with their id.

I've added the Facebook javascript and it's running, however I get this error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

What does this mean? Must my HTML5 app be running on a webserver with a domain? IE: http://foo.com/mygame.html? I was hoping to create my game and test in Chrome during development, and then push it to devices such as Android and Windows Phone. But I'm now unsure if even that works as the devices don't run a webserver.

So the question is, is it possible to do it with "pure" HTML5 for the ultimate portablility or do I have to involve Phonegap (for instance) and implement their per device implementation of the Facebook API when I'm targeting mobile devices?

Comment: Are you running directly off the file system or running in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "localhost" as your App Domain in the App Settings, during development.

More threads about this:

[Facebook development in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532721/facebook-development-in-localhost)

[What am I doing wrong in localhost Facebook app development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294630/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-localhost-facebook-app-development)

[How can I add localhost:3000 to Facebook App for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910576/how-can-i-add-localhost3000-to-facebook-app-for-development)

Comment: Thanks for the links! I just tested setting "localhost" in Site URL and Mobile Site URL for my app on the dev site on facebook, did not work

Comment: do you have a local server running? i am sure you need that, brackets is perfect for that because it creates a node.js server with the live preview, for example.