# Testing facebook javascript Login from localhost domain

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have just followed the excellent guide here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0 on how to enable facebook login for a website using the Javascript SDK.

I have tried it - and when I click my nice log in button I get the error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I note the URL for this error :

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?scope=public_profile%2Cemail&response_type=none&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Freturn%2Farbiter%3Frelation%3Dopener%26close%3Dtrue%23origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A56378%252Ff1c45491ec&seen_revocable_perms_nux=false&ref=LoginButton&auth_type=&default_audience&state=fdcac98d4&app_id=251165285007053&client_id=251165285007053&display=popup
```

So I go to my facebook app and add in my no-ip hostname, and 'localhost' - it doesnt like localhost so I remove it.

However I still get the message as the request is still being sent from domain localhost.

Is there a way I can test this running locally? I do not have a domain to deploy to during development.

Comment: The answer was found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294630/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-localhost-facebook-app-development

Comment: did u find the answer...??

Answer (score 1):

In your app configuration, you should set your website URL to `http://localhost/`

If you're using a specific localhost port, you MUST include that (e.g. `http://localhost:64321/`